# Early maariv on 2nd day Yom Tov

Tags: yom-tov, halacha, tefilla, maariv, zemanim

A shul in my city made an early maariv for the 2nd day of yom tov.  Knowing who the Rabbi is, he did not do this out of ignorance.  There are 2 issues I am unclear about:

1. Are there contemporary sources that allow switching your mincha-maariv cutoff even in the absence of adding kedusha (Tosefes).  (This would be less of an issu if the 2nd day were shabbos or early maariv on the first day if you hold there is a mitzva of tosefes for yom tom)
2. How does this circumvent the hachana issue.  Granted you accepted the 2nd day, but that shouldn't negate the first day in terms of melacha, especially since they are 2 kedushas.

Any insight?

Comment: I recently had the opportunity to speak to the Rabbi, and brought this up as a btw, I was interested...  He said like Yahu, although none of the members I spoke to knew that.  Perhaps he announced it at the minyan at which my friends didn't attend.

Comment: http://www.ykr.org.il/modules/Ask/answer/6693

Comment: see Ben ish Chai Translated into English where he takes for granted that one *can* accept Yom Tov Sheni early https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/104656/can-yom-tov-candles-be-lit-at-daytime-if-forgotten-at-night/104672#104672

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After asking a local *poseik* who is a famous expert in the *halachos* of *Yomtov Sheini* regarding this issue, these are some of his comments:

1. If the *minha* is *davened* before *plag* then a lack of *tosefes kedushas hayom* is not a problematic factor.
2. It does **not** negate the first day in terms of *melacha* and therefore it can lead to many *michsholim* (errors) regarding *hachanah* and ***melachos di'oraisa*** and therefore **it should not be done**.

Comment: So, for example, if they cook, they have to start after they accept yom tov, but they have to be ready to eat before sundown?

Comment: Yes. Look at any typical zmanim calendar and you will see how hard that is to pull off!

Comment: @Yahu Shouldn't be that hard. Maariv on Yom Tov takes 15 minutes and Plag is 1.25 hours before sunset. That leaves 1 hour to walk home and say kiddush. Should be more than sufficient.

Comment: @DoubleAA I totally assumed you were referring to my first issue because I could not figure out for the life of me why ending davening with more than enough time to get home and make kiddush would allay the issue of doing melachos on the first day for the second day. Just because you made kiddush does not mean that the first day of Yom Tov is over with regard to the issue of doing melacha on one day for next.

Comment: @Yahu I'm just saying there is plenty of time to get to the meal before sunset (having most stuff cooked before hand anyway as most families do nowadays anyway; maybe they'd heat up some liquids after plag). A rabbi should clarify the laws for his congregants and everything should be fine. I'm not saying a shul rav couldn't reasonably choose knowing his community to avoid the issue, but it doesn't seem to me to be completely insurmountable by every community. Having the option can actually make a world of difference for, eg., families with young children on 2nd day Shavuot in the summer.

Comment: I note too that in many cases the women will not be at shul for maariv (for better or worse) and can begin prep right at plag.

Comment: @DoubleAA you took the comment about the women right out of my fingertips! As far as the issue of a meal being completely prepared, there are issues which could very likely crop up at the meal itself. One example would be borer, permitted p'soles mitoch ochel, at the table. This would be a problem bain hashemashos as well, misafeik. And a Rav could know his community from alef to tav, they could very likely forget. People forget about the issue of melacha from Yomtov Rishon to Sheini bein hashemashos without confusing matters by accepting yomtov early. A fortiori in this kind of situation!

Comment: @Yahu Sorry, I don't follow the boreir example. You couldn't do boreir for use right then lest in those few seconds it switch from today to tomorrow?

Comment: @DoubleAA Absolutely correct. It is mefurash in poskim that every moment of Bein HaShemashos is a safek from one to the next. Perhaps the first second is the first day and the next second is the second day.

Comment: @Yahu And what is the concern? Hachana? Or that somehow the Miyad part of Boreir fails? I still don't follow. I want it separated _now_. That's Miyad. Even if I end up eating it after Yom Tov, I want it separated now.

Comment: @Yahu How is this different then eating Shalosh Seudos during Bein HaShemashot, as many do weekly?

Comment: @DoubleAA The problem is worse than Hachana. Melacha on Yomtov for another time is forbidden from Torah law. Each moment may be the next day from the last moment. Anything which would normally be a permitted melacha for tzorech ochel is forbidden in this time since there is a safek di'oreisa.

Comment: @Yahu So I can't carry my key from Shul to my house in order to let myself in during Bein HaShemashot between YTs? What about just pushing a stroller on a walk in the park? Who has ever heard of such a Chumra?

Comment: @DoubleAA the discussion is not about a Chumra. This is plain Halacha. Even if you have never heard about it.

Comment: My point is no one avoids walking with a stroller during Bein HaShemashot. There is clearly something missing in your logic.

Comment: @DoubleAA, have you ever lived in a place where there is no Eruv?

Comment: @Yahu Yes, actually. Not to mention all the people that I know who don't hold of Eruvin on Deoraysas. Not to mention how few (if any) communities check their Eruvin before a weekday Yom Tov.

Comment: @DoubleAA, pardon me. I just checked my notes: For a Dirabanan, if the benefit will be, or could very well be during bein hashemashos, then carrying in a Karmelis is permitted. However carrying in a Reshus Harrabim MiDiOraisa during bein Hashemashos is forbidden.

Comment: "For a Dirabanan, if the benefit will be, or could very well be during bein hashemashos, then carrying in a Karmelis is permitted." Why would that be, if nightfall may be any moment? How is that different from just doing a full fledged issur Derabanan on Friday evening after sunset?

Comment: For a source on this please see Sefer YomTov Sheini KiHilchaso pg 321

Comment: The fact that many people wheel their carriages along Ocean Parkway during Bein Hashemashos on Yomtov is merely a Re'aiya that Amaratzus is prevalent amongst us.

Comment: @DoubleAA,carrying in a Karmelis is a Dirabbanan to begin with. Rav Shlomo Zalman was meikil regarding this issue because of the fact that although logic dictates that melacha should be completely forbidden during this period, since it is not mentioned explicitly in the Poskim, if one would benefit from it during bein Hashmashos, then the dirabbanan can be done then. I fail to understand your comparison to Friday night. Elaborate please

Comment: @Yahu Friday after Shkiya before Tzeit is Safek Yom Safek Layla. So using a cell phone (let's call that a derabanan) should be a safek derabanan and muttar. Or at least it seems completely comparable to doing Hotzaat Karmelit Bein HaShemashot at the end of (either first or second day) Yom Tov.

Comment: (I don't see anything relevant on pg 321 of YTSheni Kehilchaso. This issue has nothing to do with YTSheni anyway as far as I can tell. The same would apply during the end of the one day of YT in Israel too.)

Comment: Your are logically correct. Rav Shlomo Zalman said a novel (and imho excellent) sevara to allow even Di'Oraisas in Bein Hashemashos on Yomtov as long as they are Tzoech Ochel/Shaveh Lichol Nefesh/Mitoch (feeling compelled to explain why there is no mention in the poskim of such an obvious problem) but since R' Akiva Eiger and others explicitly paskened that DiOraisa is not allowed, because of Chashash issur DiOraisa, therefore he deferred to them. But on Dirabbanans, safek Dirabbanan likulah in this instance since he does have a great sevara to permit it. more-->

Comment: The logic is that Melacha which is permitted on YomTov is Hutra, meaning the prohibition was never effectuated. (This is the Ran's approach). Being that this is the case, only if the intention of the person is for the next day would this action now be prohibited. But you cannot say that the intention is for the next day, as it is a safek what that next second is (or for that matter what the last second was). Therefore if his intention is for immediate benefit it should be allowed. He only was willing to apply this to Dirabbanans out of deference to greater earlier authorities.

Comment: The English version or the Lashon HaKodesh version? The reason he discusses it is because it is very common between two days of YomTov because people don't perceive them as two days.

Comment: Another good source on this is Rabbi Simcha Bunim Cohen's "The Laws of Yom Tov"

Comment: The Mishna Berura 514 sk 33 says you can light candles during Bein HaShemashot since you need the light then since it's almost dark. Clearly this position isn't universally held and a Posek is well within his rights ("relying" on the Mishna Berura) to not worry about it and bring in Yom Tov Sheni early.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of authorities who allow taking in the second day of yom tov early.  From my quick review of the sources they do not discuss the issue of tosefes.

See Aruch Hashulchan Orach Chaim 668:6 and Yom Tov Sheni Kehilchato p. 37.

The Taz (Orach Chaim 489:10) was against this practice but see response in Sha’ar HaTziyun 668:11

additional sources that support this practice especially for the second day of Shavuot http://www.adathisraelsf.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=359:beginning-the-2nd-day-of-shavuot-early&catid=24

for the sephardic custom [see here](https://www.jewishlinknj.com/features/25226-demystifying-the-early-acceptance-of-yom-tov-sheini-at-shaarei-orah)

It seems from this last source that:

> even after praying Arvit and reciting Kiddush early, the day fundamentally remains the first day of Yom Tov.

Here I am editorializing but this may be how both of your issues are addressed; there is no need for tosefes and no hachana because it is still the first day. I don't profess to truly understand this however, and it is not clear to me when, from the Ashkenazik perspective, one should light candles.