# Bringing in Yom Tov Sheni early

Tags: halacha, zemanim, yom-tov, kiddush, maariv

The Ben Ish Hai [Parshat Bamidbar Din 2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14054&st=&pgnum=148) holds it is permissible (and even recommended in Bagdhad), to bring in the second day of Shavuot early -- to daven and to make kiddush while it is still daytime of the first day. I've never seen anybody actually do this, and I'd like to find out whether this is a psak that's unique to the Ben Ish Hai, or whether it's universally accepted, or whether it's a machloket.

Can anyone share sources that corroborate or refute this Ben Ish Hai?

Comment: Note that this is similar to http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6999/early-maariv-on-2nd-day-yom-tov, but here I'm asking for sources for something that he just assumes.

Answer (score 4):

This question is discussed by R. Henkin in [Bnei Banim vol 3 #2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20024&st=&pgnum=10). In his teshuva he provides more sources.

The biggest potential pitfall is cooking/preparing food that will only be used on the next halachic day. Consumption of all cooked dishes would need to begin before bein hashmashos according to the Pri Megadim M"Z 503:1 (cited in the Biur Halacha ad loc). If I remember correctly, R. Shlomo Zalman Auerbach in Shulchan Shlomo is more lenient, but this would at most be only until tzeis hakochavim.

Comment: Sounds like he says the Taz 489:10 and Aruch HaShulchan 668:6 both disagree that one can start the second day early. I'll have to look at this in more detail, but this teshuva is a great starting point.

Answer (score 1):

See the *Journal of Halacha and Contemporary Society* Spring 1998 Volume # 35, "The Early Yom Tov Sheini." (pp. 62-78).  This article offers an in depth analysis of the issues.

Comment: You should summarize the article ands give an actual on line link. Just giving a citation is not enough.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya!

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya.  We're looking for answers that are complete on their own; of course references are good (and links are even better), but we prefer that the key information be here.  Could you add a short summary of what it says, or perhaps quote the abstract?  Thanks.