# Can Yom Tov candles be lit at daytime if forgotten at night?

Tags: halacha, yom-tov, candle-lighting, daytime

If one were to forget to light candles on Yom Tov eve, but remembers the next morning - can s/he still fulfill his obligation to light candles during Yom Tov day with a Brocha?

(Being daytime, it will only be *tosefes oir*, and may only be valid if done by the *seuda*, where the increased lighting is considered valid - the same as lighting by night when there are already lights in the room.)

Comment: שרגא בטיהרא מאי אהני?

Comment: @JoelK If does מהני will it help? we do light Shabbos candles in full electric lighting adding nothing practically. On the other hand, does it still add Shlom Bays - the original reason?

Comment: That' why I added *Tosefes Ohr* - it works bmokom achila

Comment: If no rishonim suggest this, it would indicate that your claim that tosefes ohr works is incorrect

Comment: I vaguely recall reading that the purpose of the candle lighting isn't as much for the light but to enhance the *makom se'udah* as well as to bring a sense of *shalom* to the house. It's questionable whether the 1st reason would aply during the daytime as you will have a *se'udah* there. But, the *shalom* aspect is perhaps "gone" as Yom Tov itself has its own sense of "Shalom" and the candle lighting is, in a sense to "enhance" it only at its onset.

Comment: DanF - There are three reasons cited in the Gemara/Rishonim for hadlakah: Kovod , Oneg and Shalom Bayis. The Poskim are clear that even when there is a source of light, one is yotzei with *tosefes oir*, provided that it is *bmokom achilah*, where having candles is considered an added ambiance.

Answer (score -1):

The Ben Ish Chai in [Rav Pealim vol 4 Orach Hayyim 23](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=1402#p=187&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=) when adressing the question of lighting candles early on *Yom Tov Sheini* mentions various opinions:

- The Sma (Rav Yehoshua falik haCohen) says in the name of his mother that one must light when it is dark as lighting earlier will only be *hachana* (preperation) for when it is dark and candles will not be needed during the day. Only in Shul it is permitted and A Mitzva to light candles early where the candles are need for the communitity to learn and Daven .
- The [Levush (Rav Mordechai Yafe) Orach Chaim 488](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=41185#p=155&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=), Eliyah Rabbah, and the Shla say one can light just before it gets dark i.e when people are walking to Shul to Daven as even though it is Safek Yom tov Rishon/Sheini one still needs the light at that point and it is better to light before the husband accepts *Yomtov Sheni* in Davening at *Borchu* (like on a Regular Shabbos).
- The Ben Ish Chai concludes that the Sma would only say to light candles after dark when Kiddush is made after dark.
  But everyone would agree that if on made Kiddush while it is light (e.g before Shekia after Plag Hamincha), since there is an obligation SA OC 243,7 to light candles for *Kavod Shabbat/Yomtov* i.e in honour of Shabbos when Shabbos commences when one makes Kiddush, so everyone would say it is *Letzorech* (the candles are needed) even during the day.
  But the Sheyarie Knesses Hagedola (Rav Chaim Beneviste) insists that lighting candles while it is light for *Kavod shabbos* is not enough of a reason and one must have long enough candles to last till the night otherwise a the Bracha recited is a *Bracha Levatala* during the daylight. But apparently some Poskim permit even only for the sake of *kavod Shabbos* during the day.

**In conclusion:** The Mitzva of lighting candles during the day only applies when accepting YomTov/ Shabbos early for in honor of the onset of Shabbos *Kavod Shabbos/Yomtov*, according to some opinions this alone is a Mitzva, and according to many there *has* to be some benefit from the candles during the night otherwise a *Bracha Levatala*.
So the next morning lighting candles is *not* a Mitzva as one has missed the oppertunity at the onset of Yomtov to mark the occasion by lighting candles.

Comment: I don't see anything here that answers the question. (He wasn't asking accd to the opinions that forbid lighting candles during daylight.)

Comment: @doubleaa everyone seems to permit lighting during the day in a Beis Haknesses for tosefes ohr even before night as mentioned by the levush i quoted, my point is that there is no mitzva to light with a Brocha during the day

Comment: Well researched, but not really relevant. This answer addresses lighting on EREV YOM TOV while it is still daylight. In other words, this answer discusses the *earliest* time for lighting, not the *latest*. You are also mixing two things - the *hanaah* from the neiros, and the obligation to kindle lights when *kovod* is nikkar.

Comment: @chortkov2  the Shela clearly states the essence of the Mitzva is to light when Yomtov commences and to not say Borchu until one has lit the candles. Even though the Sma says one can light after Davening this because it is forbidden to prepare from first day Yomtov to second day so one has no choice but to light at first oppurtunity at night. But it is clear that outside a Beis Hamidrash there is no mitzva for lighting duning the day unless accepting second day early according to Ben ish Chai.

Comment: User15464 - With all the *mareh mekomos*, you still haven't bought any proof to the fact that *bdeieved*, if somebody did not light at the beginning of Yom Tov (when he should have *lechatchila*), he should not light the next morning.

Comment: @chortkov2 i've edited it to make it more clear you can check up the link to see the Hebrew "the Sheyarie Knesses Hagedola (Rav Chaim Beneviste) insists that lighting candles while it is light for Kavod shabbos is not enough of a reason and one must have long enough candles to last till the night otherwise a the Bracha recited is a Bracha Levatala during the daylight" this means lighting during the day is a Brocho levatala whichever day.